# How do I get the value of a hidden field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following generic code to get hidden fields. If the hidden GUID is null, I show an error.

```
 $.validator.addMethod("isNotEmptyGuidtest", function (value, element, params) {
            debugger;
            var val = $.trim($(params[0]).val())

            if (val.length > 0) {

                if (val == "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
                    if ($(element).hasClass("notRequired") && $.trim(value).length == 0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }, $.format("Incorrect {1}"));
```

However, `var val = $.trim($(params[0]).val())` is not always giving me hidden field value. I don't know why. Please guide me to get the correct value of hidden fields.

Comment: What is the value of `params[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ignore:hidden` from your validations(If you have) then it will work for the hidden fields also